# Tensor product over $\mathbb Z[T]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, tensor-products

Let $k$ be a field and $\mathbb{Z} \rightarrow k$ be the canonical morphism.
Let $\mathbb{Z}[T] \rightarrow k[T]$ be the morphism where $T$ goes to $T$.

Now, consider the morphism $\mathbb{Z}[T] \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}[U,V]$ where $T$ goes to $UV$. Thus, $\mathbb{Z}[U,V]$ is a free module over $\mathbb{Z}[T]$.

Now I want to compute the $\mathbb{Z}[U,V] \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[T]} k[T]$. My guess is that it is $k[T]$-algebra $k[U,V]$, where $T$ goes to $UV$. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Since $k[T_1, ... , T_n] = \mathbb Z[T_1, ... , T_n] \otimes_{\mathbb Z} k$ and $\mathbb Z[U,V] = \mathbb Z[T] \otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb Z[T]$,

$$\mathbb Z[U,V] \otimes_{\mathbb Z[T]} k[T] = \mathbb Z[T] \otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb Z[T] \otimes_{\mathbb Z[T]} \mathbb Z[T] \otimes_{\mathbb Z} k = \mathbb Z[T] \otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb Z[T] \otimes_{\mathbb Z} k = k[U,V]$$